# How to jump out a loop after 2 cases?

Tags: php, foreach

There is a loop in the function I want to modify:

```
foreach ( $form_fields as $key => $val ) {
        if ( 'menu_order' == $key ) {
            if ( $gallery )
                $order = "<div class='menu_order'> <input class='menu_order_input' type='text' id='attachments[$attachment_id][menu_order]' name='attachments[$attachment_id][menu_order]' value='" . esc_attr( $val['value'] ). "' /></div>";
            else
                $order = "<input type='hidden' name='attachments[$attachment_id][menu_order]' value='" . esc_attr( $val['value'] ) . "' />";

            unset( $form_fields['menu_order'] );
            break;
        }
    }
```

This loop is looping through $form_fields array. if "menu_order" is the key, then, do something and break. Now I want to add one more key to do things as the above. So, I modified it as following:

```
foreach ( $form_fields as $key => $val ) {
    if ( 'menu_order' == $key ) {
        if ( $gallery )
            $order = "<div class='menu_order'> <input class='menu_order_input' type='text' id='attachments[$attachment_id][menu_order]' name='attachments[$attachment_id][menu_order]' value='" . esc_attr( $val['value'] ). "' /></div>";
        else
            $order = "<input type='hidden' name='attachments[$attachment_id][menu_order]' value='" . esc_attr( $val['value'] ) . "' />";

        unset( $form_fields['menu_order'] );

    }

    if ( 'post_status' == $key ) {
    if ( $gallery )
        $status = "<div class='post_status'> <input class='post_status_input' type='text' id='attachments[$attachment_id][post_status]' name='attachments[$attachment_id][post_status]' value='" . esc_attr( $val['value'] ). "' /></div>";
    else
        $status = "<input type='hidden' name='attachments[$attachment_id][post_status]' value='" . esc_attr( $val['value'] ) . "' />";

    unset( $form_fields['post_status'] );
    break;
}

}
```

Please note that I removed the break in original code, add the break at the end of the loop. I think this should make the loop going till it finished my newly added block.
But this code doesn't print the post_status input box as expected. Where did I go wrong in the loop?

Comment: Irresponsible and irritating vote down zealots! Seems the site need to pay attention on their negative input to the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple fix: Get rid of the loop. Since you know the keys, you don't need it, just do this to access the array elements directly:

```
if ( $gallery )
    $order = "<div class='menu_order'> <input class='menu_order_input' type='text' id='attachments[$attachment_id][menu_order]' name='attachments[$attachment_id][menu_order]' value='" . esc_attr( $form_fields['menu_order']['value'] ). "' /></div>";
else
    $order = "<input type='hidden' name='attachments[$attachment_id][menu_order]' value='" . esc_attr( $form_fields['menu_order']['value'] ) . "' />";

unset( $form_fields['menu_order']);
```

Do the same for the `'post_status'` field.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to break the loop after both `$order` and `$status` are found. If so, you want to have an additional if statement after both cases to check and make sure that both `$order` and `$status` are set, and only break if that's the case.

Something like:

```
if (isset($order) && isset($status)) {
    break;
}
```

That said, check the function as well. It may be only checking the value of `$order`, and ignoring the value of `$status`.

Comment: I also didn't look carefully enough at the loop. Nick's answer is also correct in that a loop isn't necessary at all.

Comment: Thanks! I will use Nick's solution in this code. I will remember your "break" method for future in cases I want to break a loop in the middle.